# How to to make 2 MapView on one Activity?

Tags: android

Is it possible to make 2 MapView on one Activity ?

If so, How to make it ?

I've tried but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is **no**.

Currently Android supports only one MapView per MapActivity.

Comment: @Reto Meier How about Using Two SupportMapFragment in One FragmentActivity?I use it but it create this kind of Problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946152/using-two-supportmapfragment-in-one-activity-but-unable-remove-marker-from-secon

Answer (score 0):

**yes possible**, I used this code for two different kinds of maps------ **1.** for getting gps location------**2.** for getting some location when it is searched by its area/city/country name. The code is,

```
    public void mapDisplay(double lat, double lng, int arg){

        if(arg == 1){
            mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map_view);
        }
        else if (arg ==2 ){
            mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map_view2);

        }

        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        //mapView.setStreetView(true);
        //mapView.setTraffic(true);
        //mapView.setSatellite(true);

        // to display the pin point
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
        CustomItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int)(lng * 1E6));

        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");
        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

        mapView.getController().setZoom(18);
        mapView.getController().setCenter(point);
        mapView.getController().animateTo(point);

        mapView.invalidate();

 }
```

**Note:** Make sure that you have set the ContentViews before calling this method and

> int arg

is used here to indicate that which mapView is going to be called.....I used