# Android: Google Maps error android.view.InflateException

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

I am creating an application with Google Maps, Fragment and View Pager.

But I got the following error:

```
02-06 11:56:58.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1675): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

02-06 11:56:58.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1675): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #246: Error inflating class fragment

02-06 11:56:58.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)**
```

in the line:

```
**v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detalle_mon_fragment, container, false);**
```

This is my code:

**DetalleMonumentoFragment.java**

```
public class ActivityFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {  

    public static final ActivityFragment newInstance(String mon){

        ActivityFragment f = new ActivityFragment();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);

        bdl.putString("mon", mon);
        f.setArguments(bdl);
        return f;
    }

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    context = getActivity();

    mon = getArguments().getString("mon");

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detalle_mon_fragment, container, false);
...
}
```

**detalle_mon_fragment.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/mapaTab"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

What can be the error? thanks

**EDIT:**

New error now:

02-06 12:15:42.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1965): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #246: Duplicate id 0x7f060039, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

```
    public static final int mapa2=0x7f060051;
    public static final int mapaMain=0x7f060013;
    public static final int mapaTab=0x7f060039;
```

I have a Activity with a Map and onClick open other Map.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mapaTab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: why? Without Linearlayout?

Comment: No, of course. Just replace class= with android:name= inside your fragment tag.

Comment: It seems that you have a duplicate id: are you using again an id "@+id/mapaTab"?

Comment: No,         public static final int mapa2=0x7f060051;
        public static final int mapaMain=0x7f060013;
        public static final int mapaTab=0x7f060039;

Comment: Where you add the other map?

Comment: Have a look at this [multiple-map-views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609748/multiple-map-views)

Comment: In the above activity. i have learned your link... but i dont solved my error

Comment: But do you have the error when shwoing the second map?

Comment: So if you are trying to display two maps in the same Activity it seems not to be possible. If you are using two different activities It seems needed to run them into separate process. [multiple-map-activities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379575/how-to-use-multiple-mapactivities-mapviews-per-android-application-process/3380655#3380655)

Comment: in the last comment, it says api v2 allow various maps

Comment: It seems so, but I don't konw that. Try to follow its links