# android:load mapview inside the activity

Tags: android, android-maps

I have create the list-activity.Now I want to add new view with with map so that i can switch between views on menu select.Can anyone tell how to load the map inside the same activity? it is necessary to take the map-activity to draw the map?
i read some links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018929/how-to-to-make-2-mapview-on-one-activity)

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have check some of the post and find out that for map view we need to extends the mapActivity.

If anyone have done it then please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ViewAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html) and have two child ListView and MapView.
Your class should extend MapActivity and you can switch back and forth using ViewAnimator.

Comment: thank for response,let me try it,if you have any tutorials then please post here

Comment: i think that's not possible without the MapActivity,if you have done then can you post the code here?