# Using Two SupportMapFragment in one Activity but unable remove Marker from Second SupportMapFragment that i have added in First SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I have  strange issue while using Two SupportMapFragment in two different Fragment in one Activity.

Actually my problem is let say In OneFragment i have SupprtMapFragment added and i add 10 Marker in that map view and now i go to detail page by adding another Fragment and in that it have also SupprtMapFragment now in this Fragment i want to clear it and want to show Only one pin but it Still Showing 11 Marker over map .

Here is my Source code:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private FragmentManager mFragmrg;

    public static String TAG_FRAGMENT_HOME="HomeFragment";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        initView();
    }



    private void initView(){

        mFragmrg=getSupportFragmentManager();

        MapHomeFragment mMapHomeFragment=new MapHomeFragment();

        FragmentTransaction mFt=mFragmrg.beginTransaction();


        mFt.replace(R.id.frame_holder, mMapHomeFragment, TAG_FRAGMENT_HOME).addToBackStack(TAG_FRAGMENT_HOME).commit();



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

XMl Layout of Activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MapActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

THis Fragment have my First SupportMapFragment where i want to show more then 11 Marker over map and it work well.

```
public class MapHomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnInfoWindowClickListener,OnClickListener{

    private GoogleMap mMapView;
    private FragmentManager mFragMrg;

    private SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment;


    private LatLng mLatnogGuj=new LatLng(23.0626, 72.5809);

    private LatLng mLatnogGujOne=new LatLng(18.9158, 72.8267);

    private LatLng mLatnogGujTwo=new LatLng(24.5925, 72.7156);

    private LatLng mLatnogGuj3=new LatLng(34.0837,74.7974);

    private LatLng mLatnogGuj4=new LatLng(23.2245, 72.6379);

    private LatLng mLatnogGuj5=new LatLng(12.9716, 77.5946);

    private LatLng mLatnogGuj6=new LatLng(23.0396, 72.5660);

    private LatLng mLatnogGuj7=new LatLng(22.3140, 73.1748);

    private LatLng mLatnogGuj8=new LatLng(20.5732, 73.7442);
    private LatLng mLatnogGuj9=new LatLng(21.1785, 72.8191);
    private LatLng mLatnogGuj10=new LatLng(28.6644, 77.2349);

    private LatLngBounds.Builder mLatlongBuilder;

    private Button mBtnMapDetail;


    private ViewSwitcher mViewSwitcher;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View mView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_map, container, false);


        initView(mView);

        return mView;
    }


    private void initView(View mView){

        mViewSwitcher=(ViewSwitcher)mView.findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher);

        mViewSwitcher.showNext();

        try{
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        }catch(Exception Exc){
            Exc.printStackTrace();
        }

        mBtnMapDetail=(Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_mapdetail);
        mBtnMapDetail.setOnClickListener(this);

        mFragMrg=getFragmentManager();

        mSupportMapFragment=(SupportMapFragment) mFragMrg.findFragmentByTag("map_home_fragment");


        if(mSupportMapFragment!=null){

            mMapView=mSupportMapFragment.getMap();

            if(mMapView!=null){


                //mMapView.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

                mMapView.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

                mMapView.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

                mMapView.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

                mMapView.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

                mMapView.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoViewAdapter(getActivity()));


                mLatlongBuilder=new LatLngBounds.Builder();

                MarkerOptions mMarkerOption=new MarkerOptions();
                mMarkerOption.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGuj).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map)).snippet("My Name is");
                mLatlongBuilder.include(mLatnogGuj);

                mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption);


                MarkerOptions mMarkerOption1=new MarkerOptions();
                mMarkerOption1.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGujOne).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_pub)).snippet("My Name is");
                mLatlongBuilder.include(mLatnogGujOne);

                mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption1);

                MarkerOptions mMarkerOption2=new MarkerOptions();
                mMarkerOption2.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGujTwo).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_rest)).snippet("My Name is");
                mLatlongBuilder.include(mLatnogGujTwo);

                mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption2);

                MarkerOptions mMarkerOption3=new MarkerOptions();
                mMarkerOption3.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGuj3).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_small)).snippet("My Name is");
                mLatlongBuilder.include(mLatnogGuj3);
                mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption3);


                MarkerOptions mMarkerOption4=new MarkerOptions();
                mMarkerOption4.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGuj4).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_take)).snippet("My Name is");
                mLatlongBuilder.include(mLatnogGuj4);
                mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption4);

                MarkerOptions mMarkerOption5=new MarkerOptions();
                mMarkerOption5.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGuj5).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_top)).snippet("My Name is");
                mLatlongBuilder.include(mLatnogGuj5);
                mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption5);


                MarkerOptions mMarkerOption6=new MarkerOptions();
                mMarkerOption6.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGuj6).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_top_hover)).snippet("My Name is");
                mLatlongBuilder.include(mLatnogGuj6);
                mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption6);


                MarkerOptions mMarkerOption7=new MarkerOptions();
                mMarkerOption7.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGuj7).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_pub)).snippet("My Name is");
                mLatlongBuilder.include(mLatnogGuj7);
                mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption7);

                MarkerOptions mMarkerOption8=new MarkerOptions();
                mMarkerOption8.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGuj8).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_rest)).snippet("My Name is");
                mLatlongBuilder.include(mLatnogGuj8);
                mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption8);

                MarkerOptions mMarkerOption9=new MarkerOptions();
                mMarkerOption9.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGuj9).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_small)).snippet("My Name is");
                mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption9);

                mLatlongBuilder.include(mLatnogGuj9);


                MarkerOptions mMarkerOption10=new MarkerOptions();
                mMarkerOption10.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGuj10).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_take)).snippet("My Name is");

                mLatlongBuilder.include(mLatnogGuj10);

                mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption10);

                //mMapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mLatlongBuilder.build(), 120));

                mBtnMapDetail.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        mMapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mLatlongBuilder.build(), 120));

                    }
                }, 250);

            }


        }



    }


    public class CustomInfoViewAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{


        View mLayoutInfo;


        public CustomInfoViewAdapter(Context _Context){


            LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) _Context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            mLayoutInfo=mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);



        }



        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            return mLayoutInfo;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

            return null;
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        intiDetailFragment();

    }


    private void intiDetailFragment(){

        MapDetailFragment mMapDetailFragment=new MapDetailFragment();

        FragmentTransaction mFt=mFragMrg.beginTransaction();

        mFt.add(R.id.frame_holder, mMapDetailFragment, "DetailFragment").addToBackStack("DetailFragment").commit();
    }


}
```

OUTPUT Screen Shot:
[image: SupportMap One with 11 Marker]

Now when you click that DetailMap button it will take user to Detail Screen where i want to show only One Marker in that SupportMapFragment but i don't known why it still Showing previous all Marker which i have added in my First Fragment.

My Second Fragment Code:

```
public class MapDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMapView;

    private SupportMapFragment mSupportMapDetail;

    private FragmentManager mFragMrg;

    private LatLng mLatnogGujOne=new LatLng(18.9158, 72.8267);

    private LatLngBounds.Builder mLatlongBuilder;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_detail_screen, container,
                false);

        intView(mView);

        return mView;
    }

    private void intView(View mView) {

        mFragMrg=getChildFragmentManager();

        mSupportMapDetail=(SupportMapFragment) mFragMrg.findFragmentByTag("map_home_detail");



        if(mSupportMapDetail!=null){

            mGoogleMapView=mSupportMapDetail.getMap();

            if(mGoogleMapView!=null){

                mGoogleMapView.clear();

                mGoogleMapView.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

                mGoogleMapView.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

                mGoogleMapView.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

                mGoogleMapView.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

                mGoogleMapView.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                mLatlongBuilder=new LatLngBounds.Builder();

                MarkerOptions mMarkerOption=new MarkerOptions();

                mMarkerOption.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGujOne).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_pub)).snippet("My Name is");
                mLatlongBuilder.include(mLatnogGujOne);

                mGoogleMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption);


                mGoogleMapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mLatlongBuilder.build(), 120));

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Here is my xml code of home_map.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_mapdetail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mapdetail" />

    <ViewSwitcher
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewSwitcher"
         >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llMapDemo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map_home_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:tag="map_home_fragment" />
    </ViewSwitcher>

</LinearLayout>
```

another xml is here map_detail_screen.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/empty_photo" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/empty_photo" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/empty_photo" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/empty_photo" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/empty_photo" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/empty_photo" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map_home_fragment_detail"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:tag="map_home_detail" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here is my Second screen output:

[image: SupportMap Second Screen]

As you can see in my second screen show it still showing Marker on map Why this happen ?

Can any one give proper solution so when i go back in previous screen it have all Marker remain as same as i have added them .

Comment: Looks like the 2nd fragment is never displayed.  That's why it seems like you can't remove the markers.

Comment: @danny117 Yes Second Map Fragment have only one Marker but still Some how First Map Fragment overlap over it .

Comment: @danny117 And i have found one Solution like from this https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5027 But still not satisfied to use that approach to hide my First Fragment by reducing it width and height to 1 .Although i have check and it work well but still looking for Good Solution.

Comment: @Herry Do you got any solution? I have a similar problem.

Comment: @user2894326 Yes i made solution by setting width and height of first Map Fragment to near to 1 (Width) and 1 (Height).if you want more let me find it for you.

Comment: i have a small map in first fragment and while clicking on that  another fragment will come that have a full mapview. But in some phones like sony experia both mapa are showing ie. first on the top of second.Do u have any idea?

Comment: Yes this will happen even you are commit new Fragment for Second Fragment in that your First map will show like overlapping in that can do this for your First fragment get it's View set view.getLayoutParams().width=1 and view.getLayoutParams().height=1; Now when you come back then again you need to set As previous normal view side of it.

Comment: i tried. I put these in onpause and onresume.But it is not working.I tried this with both mapview and mapfragment . One thing i noticed is onpause is not calling while moving to next fragment.Where should i place these codes?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
mSupportMapDetail=(SupportMapFragment) mFragMrg.findFragmentByTag("map_home_detail");
```

with

```
mSupportMapDetail=(SupportMapFragment) mFragMrg.findFragmentById("map_home_fragment_detail");
```

Also try replacing `findFragmentByTag` to `findFragmentById` everywhere..

Comment: I just Try your answer that does not make any Effect still my First Fragment Map is overlaying Second Fragment Map .

Comment: Did you try `fragmentTransaction.replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)` instead of `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(str)` ??

Comment: Yes Using fragmentTransaction.replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag) for My MapDetailFragment to commit work but It Cause unable to add Stack so when user press back app close but in my case i want to show First Fragment .

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code to your second fragment:

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    // Hide the zoom controls as the button panel will cover it.
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

// if there were any markers remove them just in case
mMap.clear();
    // Add your marker to the map
    addMarkersToMap();

    // Setting an info window adapter allows us to change the both the contents and look of the
    // info window.
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());

    // Set listeners for marker events.  See the bottom of this class for their behavior.
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
```

}

and in your map_detail_screen.xml add:

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/map_home_fragment_detail"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you..
Note : you can not add one fragment inside another fragment.

**XML**
**activity_map**
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

**home_map**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_mapdetail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MapDetails" />

    <ViewSwitcher
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/viewSwitcher">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llMapDemo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="textview"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fram_map_home_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ViewSwitcher>
</LinearLayout>

**map_detail_screen**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

**info_window_layout**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>

**Activity**
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;


public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    private FragmentManager mFragmrg;
    public static String TAG_FRAGMENT_HOME="HomeFragment";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        initView();
    }
    private void initView(){
        mFragmrg=getSupportFragmentManager();
        MapHomeFragment mMapHomeFragment = new MapHomeFragment();
        FragmentTransaction mFt=mFragmrg.beginTransaction();
        mFt.replace(R.id.frame_holder, mMapHomeFragment, TAG_FRAGMENT_HOME).addToBackStack(TAG_FRAGMENT_HOME).commit();
    }
}

**MapHomeFragment**
package com.example.Demo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;



public class MapHomeFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener,View.OnClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMapView;
    private FragmentManager mFragMrg;
    private SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment;

    private LatLng mLatnogGuj=new LatLng(23.0626, 72.5809);
    private LatLng mLatnogGujOne=new LatLng(18.9158, 72.8267);
    private LatLng mLatnogGujTwo=new LatLng(24.5925, 72.7156);
    private LatLng mLatnogGuj3=new LatLng(34.0837,74.7974);
    private LatLng mLatnogGuj4=new LatLng(23.2245, 72.6379);
    private LatLng mLatnogGuj5=new LatLng(12.9716, 77.5946);
    private LatLng mLatnogGuj6=new LatLng(23.0396, 72.5660);
    private LatLng mLatnogGuj7=new LatLng(22.3140, 73.1748);
    private LatLng mLatnogGuj8=new LatLng(20.5732, 73.7442);
    private LatLng mLatnogGuj9=new LatLng(21.1785, 72.8191);
    private LatLng mLatnogGuj10=new LatLng(28.6644, 77.2349);
    private Button mBtnMapDetail;
    private ViewSwitcher mViewSwitcher;
    private MapDetailFragment mMapDetailFragment;
    private FrameLayout fram_map_home_fragment;
    private Timer t;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_map, container, false);
        fram_map_home_fragment = (FrameLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.fram_map_home_fragment);
        initView(mView);
        return mView;
    }


    private void initView(View mView){
        mViewSwitcher=(ViewSwitcher)mView.findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher);
        mViewSwitcher.showNext();

        try{
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        }catch(Exception Exc){
            Exc.printStackTrace();
        }

        mBtnMapDetail=(Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_mapdetail);
        mBtnMapDetail.setOnClickListener(this);

        mFragMrg=getFragmentManager();
        mSupportMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(fram_map_home_fragment.getId(), mSupportMapFragment);
        ft.commit();

        try{
            t = new Timer();
            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                if(mSupportMapFragment!=null){
                                    mMapView=mSupportMapFragment.getMap();
                                    if(mMapView!=null){
                                        mMapView.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                                        mMapView.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                                        mMapView.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
                                        mMapView.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
                                        mMapView.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
                                        mMapView.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(true);
                                        mMapView.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                                        mMapView.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(MapHomeFragment.this);
                                        mMapView.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoViewAdapter(getActivity()));

                                        MarkerOptions mMarkerOption=new MarkerOptions();
                                        mMarkerOption.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGuj).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)).snippet("My Name is");
                                        mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption);


                                        MarkerOptions mMarkerOption1=new MarkerOptions();
                                        mMarkerOption1.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGujOne).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)).snippet("My Name is");
                                        mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption1);

                                        MarkerOptions mMarkerOption2=new MarkerOptions();
                                        mMarkerOption2.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGujTwo).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)).snippet("My Name is");
                                        mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption2);

                                        MarkerOptions mMarkerOption3=new MarkerOptions();
                                        mMarkerOption3.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGuj3).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)).snippet("My Name is");
                                        mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption3);


                                        MarkerOptions mMarkerOption4=new MarkerOptions();
                                        mMarkerOption4.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGuj4).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)).snippet("My Name is");
                                        mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption4);

                                        MarkerOptions mMarkerOption5=new MarkerOptions();
                                        mMarkerOption5.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGuj5).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)).snippet("My Name is");
                                        mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption5);


                                        MarkerOptions mMarkerOption6=new MarkerOptions();
                                        mMarkerOption6.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGuj6).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)).snippet("My Name is");
                                        mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption6);


                                        MarkerOptions mMarkerOption7=new MarkerOptions();
                                        mMarkerOption7.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGuj7).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)).snippet("My Name is");
                                        mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption7);

                                        MarkerOptions mMarkerOption8=new MarkerOptions();
                                        mMarkerOption8.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGuj8).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)).snippet("My Name is");
                                        mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption8);

                                        MarkerOptions mMarkerOption9=new MarkerOptions();
                                        mMarkerOption9.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGuj9).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)).snippet("My Name is");
                                        mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption9);


                                        MarkerOptions mMarkerOption10=new MarkerOptions();
                                        mMarkerOption10.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGuj10).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)).snippet("My Name is");
                                        mMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption10);

                                        mMapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLatnogGujOne,4));
                                        t.cancel();
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    });

                }
            }, 0, 500);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public class CustomInfoViewAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

        View mLayoutInfo;

        public CustomInfoViewAdapter(Context _Context){
            LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) _Context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mLayoutInfo=mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            return mLayoutInfo;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        intiDetailFragment();
    }


    private void intiDetailFragment(){
        FragmentTransaction mFt=mFragMrg.beginTransaction();
        mMapDetailFragment=new MapDetailFragment();
        mFt.add(R.id.frame_holder, mMapDetailFragment, "DetailFragment").addToBackStack("DetailFragment").commit();
    }

}


**MapDetailFragment**
package com.example.Demo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class MapDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private FrameLayout frame_detail;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMapView;
    private SupportMapFragment mSupportMapDetail;
    private LatLng mLatnogGujOne=new LatLng(18.9158, 72.8267);
    private Timer t;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_detail_screen, container,false);
        frame_detail = (FrameLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.frame_detail);
        intView();
        return mView;
    }

    private void intView() {
        mSupportMapDetail = new SupportMapFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(frame_detail.getId(), mSupportMapDetail);
        ft.commit();

        try{
            t = new Timer();
            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(mSupportMapDetail!=null){
                                mGoogleMapView=mSupportMapDetail.getMap();
                                if(mGoogleMapView!=null){
                                    mGoogleMapView.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                                    mGoogleMapView.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                                    mGoogleMapView.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
                                    mGoogleMapView.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
                                    mGoogleMapView.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
                                    mGoogleMapView.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(true);
                                    mGoogleMapView.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                                    MarkerOptions mMarkerOption=new MarkerOptions();
                                    mMarkerOption.title("Map One").position(mLatnogGujOne).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)).snippet("My Name is");
                                    mGoogleMapView.addMarker(mMarkerOption);
                                    mGoogleMapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLatnogGujOne,8));
                                    t.cancel();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            }, 0, 500);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

**AndroidManifest.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.Demo"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name="MyActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="4030500" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyC2OdJ0WJtj5-iTAk_-MwjJNxgvFVdQoXg" />
  </application>
 </manifest>

![enter image description here][1]
![enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6swQ2.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUWnA.png
```

Comment: I just Apply your code and i found it is not working .

Comment: @Herry, have you getting such kind of error becz i also attached screenshot of my code.

Comment: Ohh i just see your Screen shot look like it's working .

Comment: I have apply your code but it seem like not work yet.Still Pins of previous Map showing in Detail Screen map.

Comment: If i replace this line `mFt.add(R.id.frame_holder, mMapDetailFragment, "DetailFragment").addToBackStack("DetailFragment").commit();` by mFt.replace(R.id.frame_holder, mMapDetailFragment, "DetailFragment").addToBackStack("DetailFragment").commit(); it is working very good but pressing backButton of Android recreate `MapHomeFragment`.

Comment: have you changed anything in code so please let me know then i try to resolve this problem.

Comment: I just put all your code in Github ,https://github.com/Himanshu4003/GoogleMapDemo I am running same project.

Comment: I am using Google-PlayService Version : android:versionName="4.3.23 (1069729-030)"

Comment: @Herry, i edited my ans and add "AndroidManifest.xml" code but you have use declare same package on your project.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51474/discussion-between-herry-and-haresh)

Comment: i apply change in Manifest as well but i don/t get it work for DatailFragment.

Comment: You can check my Code which i have post in Github ,clone it and test you can not get Proper map in Detail page.https://github.com/Himanshu4003/GoogleMapDemo